# C# ssh.net library, cd command does not work ( cannot send "/" )

Tags: c#, ssh, ssh.net

Every other command seems to work fine but it seems like I cannot send "/" using RunCommand() on ssh.net library.  I need to change my working directory to run a program using "cd /home/debian". But when I send this line nothing seems to happen. I still stay in the home directory. How can I solve this problem?

```
// start the connection
        var client = new SshClient (host, user,password);
        client.Connect();

        command = textBoxCommand.Text;   //taking the command from textbox

        if (command != "") //unless the command is empty
        {
            SshCommand sc = client.CreateCommand(command); 
            sc.Execute(); //run command
            textBoxRecieved.AppendText(command);
            textBoxRecieved.AppendText("\n");

            string answer = sc.Result;
            answer = answer.Replace("\n", "  ");
            textBoxRecieved.AppendText(sc.Error.Replace("\n", "   "));
            textBoxRecieved.AppendText(answer);

            textBoxRecieved.AppendText("\n");
            textBoxCommand.Clear();
        }

    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - provide a minimal viable complete example.. people will need way more info

Comment: "nothing seems to happen. I still stay in the home directory." How do you know this? Are you getting an error from the the code that you included in your question?

Answer (score 8):

Actuallly, the cd command was working but the probllem was that every seperate command is executed from home directory. So, when I check my directory with pwd command, I see that I am still in home directory because the new command is executed at home directory.

For anyone who face this problem, you can simply send commands that needs to be executed consecutively together by:

```
SshCommand sc = client.CreateCommand("cd /home/debian && pwd");
```